# Use variables from one Screen on another in kivy

Tags: python, function, class, variables, kivy

I'm making an app with kivy, and in my kv file I have one screen called MainScreen which has two TextInput boxes. When I press a Button, the screen will change to LoggedInScreen. How do I pass the input from the TextInput boxes on MainScreen, to LoggedInScreen, so I can use them as positional arguments on a function I defined in main.py? This is what I've tried (relevant bits of code only):

```
<LoggedInScreen>:
    name: 'loggedin'
    FloatLayout:
        TextInput:

            #This is not working
            text: root.auth(MainScreen.ids.username.text, MainScreen.ids.password.txt)

            font_name: 'PCBius.ttf'
            background_color: (73/255,73/255,73/255,1)
            keyboard_mode: 'managed'
            readonly: True
            size: 405, self.height
            pos: 495,0
<MainScreen>:
    name:'main'
    FloatLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: username
            multiline: False
            size_hint: self.width/self.width/5, self.height/self.height/16
            pos: 200,292
        TextInput:
            id: password
            password: True
            multiline: False
            size_hint: self.width/self.width/5, self.height/self.height/16
            pos: 200,232
```

But it outputs an error saying that MainScreen is not defined.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be defining a new method called `auth_success` in the screen manager, which is in charge of those two screens:

```
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

    ...

    def auth_success(self, username, password):
        self.loggedin.username = username
        self.loggedin.password = password
        self.current = 'loggedin'
```

Now, when a user successfully authenticates in the main screen, call `self.parent.auth_success(self.ids.username.text, self.ids.username.password)`.

Comment: I don't think you get what I mean, unless I don't understand (which is probably the case, I'm fairly new). When I call "MainScreen.ids.username.text", it doesn't work. So how, in LoggedInScreen, can I get the text of one of the TextInput boxes on MainScreen?

Comment: @LoganDarby I understand what you mean. You want to pass data between screens, and I gave you a simple solution for it. It's a good practice to use a screen manager, since it already manages the screens. The `MainScreen.ids.username.text` doesn't work, because you are accessing a class, not an object. Objects are stored in the screen manager as children widgets.